# How to connect HTML Input to Python Boto3 scripts

Tags: python, html, flask, boto3

I'm writing Python scripts for AWS and don't know how to pull the input value from an HTML form and have it read in Python, so that it can execute a function based on the input. I've never used Flask before.

HTML:

```
<form action="buckets.py" method="POST">
    <div class="row">
          <label id="blank">
            Name
          </label>
          <input
            style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 4px;"
            width="150"
            name="username"
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Submit Button -->
      <div class="row">
          <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
      </div>
  </form>
  
</div>
```

Python:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

# Create the connection
session = boto3.Session(region_name='us-east-2')

s3 = session.client('s3')

# Pull data form HTML Form
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/') #default route
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/create_bucket', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])

def create_bucket():
    output = request.form.to_dict()
    name = output["name"]
    bucket_name = name
    s3_location = {
        'LocationConstraint': 'us-east-2'
    }

    #  Create the S3 Bucket
    s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name, CreateBucketConfiguration=s3_location)

    return render_template('index.html')

create_bucket()
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do the following.

- you can simply use post method ajax call to send data to flask server
- you don't have to write `create_bucket()` as this function will be called
  when you hit the endpoint `/create_bucket` either through GET or POST
  method.
  So the new code of the flask side should be:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

# Create the connection
session = boto3.Session(region_name='us-east-2')

s3 = session.client('s3')

# Pull data form HTML Form
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/') #default route
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/create_bucket', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def create_bucket():
    output = request.form.to_dict()
    name = output["name"]
    bucket_name = name
    s3_location = {
        'LocationConstraint': 'us-east-2'
    }

    #  Create the S3 Bucket
    s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name, CreateBucketConfiguration=s3_location)

    return render_template('index.html')
```